# Unit tests with CakePHP 3 and PHPUnit 8 outside project

Tags: php, unit-testing, cakephp, phpunit

Is there someway to do unit testing in CakePHP 3.x with the latest version of PHPUnit?

Using composer inside the project is limited to PHPUnit version 6.

Comment: Why do you need more than v6?

Comment: Hi @mark, according to PHPUnit site (https://phpunit.de/supported-versions.html) support for v6 has ended on February 1, 2019. Not that i need more than v6 but i think its important to use last version.

Comment: No it is not important - nor necessary. Just use what the framework at this point offers. Cake4 will then use latest again, so there is no issue here.